# electron builder, mac dmg package including files for build stage

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I am using electron-builder to package my app for windows, mac, and linux.

Resulting packages are all the same size but for Mac, the file is twice that size.

There's a huge `app.asar.unpacked/` folder with frameworks from the build stage that are not needed.

How can I configure **electronbuilder** to skip these files?

**myApp.app** [image]

This is my **project.json**

```
{
  "name": "KioskeTV",
  "description": "TV Application",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "app/src/main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "install-app-deps",
    "start": "npm install && electron .",
    "pack": "build --dir",
    "dist": "build",
    "dist:win": "build --platform win32"
  },
  "repository": "https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start",
  "keywords": [
    "nobj.io",
    "service",
    "launcher"
  ],
  "author": "Nebular Streams SLU",
  "license": "Proprietary",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^2.0.0",
    "electron-builder": "^20.26.1"
  },
  "build": {
    "appId": "nobjio",
    "dmg": {
      "contents": [
        {
          "x": 110,
          "y": 150
        },
        {
          "x": 240,
          "y": 150,
          "type": "link",
          "path": "/Applications"
        }
      ]
    },
    "linux": {
      "target": [
        "AppImage",
        "deb"
      ]
    },
    "win": {
      "target": "portable",
      "icon": "build/icon.ico"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "app-builder-lib": "^20.27.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

"ignore is an electron-packager option, and, must be specified in the build"
This might get you pointed in the right direction.  Good luck.
Something like this in build:

```
ignore: function (
// TODO: add logic here
console.log(file);
return false;
```

Another Possibility:
Use https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager/blob/master/docs/api.md#ignore as regexp.